# Performing operations on RDD [(LongWritable),(JsonObject)]

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

My task is basically:

1. Read data from Google Cloud BigQuery using Spark/Scala.
2. Perform some operation (Like, Update) on the data.
3. Write back the data to BigQuery

Till now, I am able to read data from BigQuery using `newAPIHadoopRDD()` which returns `RDD[(LongWritable, JsonObject)]`.

```
tableData.map(entry => (entry._1.toString(),entry._2.toString()))
  .take(10)
  .foreach(println)
```

And below is the sample data,

```
(341,{"id":"4","name":"Shahu","score":"100"})
```

I am not able to figure out what functions should I use on this RDD to meet requirement.

Do I need to convert this RDD to DataFrame/Dataset/JSON format? and How?

Comment: What exactly you want to update? The map/reduce sometimes can be replaced with a UDF function inside BQ.

Comment: Update the data of BigQuery table through Spark/Scala.